# Drop-Down Menu Issue (Buttons Inside a button)

Tags: html, css

I have a question about creating submenus. Everything seems normal until I hover over the mouse over the last button from the left and saw that I have the three buttons *inside* the parent button. What can I do to get them out of that button? I mean, how can I show them vertically stacked and below that parent buttons container? Not sure if I'm clear on this.

Here's the code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#menutop ul {
 
 list-style-type: none;
}

#menutop li {

 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: orange;
}

#menutop li:hover {
 
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 
}

li ul {
 
 display: none;
 
 }
 
li:hover > ul {
 
 display: block;
 
 }
 
#submenu li {
 
 float: none;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Menú Práctica</title>
<link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="menutop">
<ul>
<li>Menú 1</li>
<li>Menú 2</li>
<li>Menú 3</li>
<li>Menú 4
<ul id="submenu">
<li>Menú 1</li>
<li>Menú 2</li>
<li>Menú 3</li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As I said before, this might be something pretty minimal (basically a rookie thing).

Greetings from Argentina.

Comment: Yes, I want the submenu to be shown vertically and separated from the buttom. Something like this - http://imgsafe.org/image/20202a17e5 and not like this -http://imgsafe.org/image/2021b6cd44 I was thought to do <ul> into <li> for submenus so I guess this could be why it's showing up like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use absolute-positioning on the sub-menu for that... Which is constrained via position:relative on the sub-menu's parent `li`

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#menutop ul {
 
 list-style-type: none;
}
#menutop ul > li {
    position: relative;
}
#menutop li {

 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: orange;
}

#menutop li:hover {
 
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 
}

li ul {
 
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
    top: 100%
 left: 0;
 }
 
li:hover > ul {
 
 display: block;
 
 }
 
#submenu li {
 
 float: none;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Menú Práctica</title>
<link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="menutop">
<ul>
<li>Menú 1</li>
<li>Menú 2</li>
<li>Menú 3</li>
<li>Menú 4
<ul id="submenu">
<li>Menú 1</li>
<li>Menú 2</li>
<li>Menú 3</li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the big help and appreciate you understood my English. For a moment, I thought learning the language all these years didn't pay off haha.